# Multiply odd indices by 2?

Tags: python, list

So I'm writing a function that is going to multiply each number at an odd index in a `list` by `2`. I'm stuck though, as I really don't know how to approach it.

This is my code.

```
def produkt(pnr):
    for i in pnr:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            i = i * 2
    return pnr
```

If I, for example, type `produkt([1,2,3])` I get `[1,2,3]` back but I would want it to be `[2,2,6]`.

Comment: do you want to multiply all the numbers at odd indices or all odd numbers?

Your example looks like the latter, but your question sounds like the former.

Comment: I want to multiply all the numbers at odd indices. Sorry for my bad explanation of the problem.

Comment: Alright I updated my answer. Most answers here are multiplying the odd numbers instead of numbers at odd indices.

Comment: also, your example shows _even_ indices updated (indices start at `0`)

Answer (score 3):

note that modifying `i` in your example does not change the value from the input list (integers are *immutable*). And you're also mixing up the *values* with their *position*.

Also, since indices start at `0` in python, you got it the wrong way.

In those cases, a simple list comprehension with a ternary expression will do, using `enumerate` to be able to get hold of the indices (making it start at `1` to match your case, you can adjust at will):

```
[p*2 if i%2 else p for i,p in enumerate(pnr,1)]
```

(note `if i%2` is shorter that `if i%2 != 0`)

Comment: This is quite slow, use numpy instead. (see my answer for speed test)

Answer (score 3):

using list comprehensions:

multiply odd numbers by 2:

```
[x*2 if x%2 else x for x in pnr]
```

After clarification of question wording:
multiply numbers at odd indices by 2:

```
[x*2 if i%2 else x for i,x in enumerate(pnr)]
```

Comment: note that in the example, OP multiplies the _even_ indices by 2. But whatever, this a minor issue.

Comment: `[1,2,3]` => `[2,2,6]`: even indices are multiplied all right. This is damn confusing with the values following and all I admit it (I upvoted your answer already, so relax :))

Comment: Ah yes, true, I was looking at the code, not the example In-&Output. OP should really take some care to make his question less confusing. I am going to assume he *meant* odd indices though as that is the title of the question.

Comment: Don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using **list comprehensions**:

```
def produkt(pnr):
    return [k * 2 if k % 2 else k for k in pnr]
```

Doing `i = i * 2` you just override a local variable.

**UPDATE (question was changed):**

```
def produkt(pnr):
    return [k * 2 if i % 2 else k for i, k in enumerate(pnr, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the indices using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate), however that starts by default with index `0` (not `1`) but it accepts a start argument to override that default.

The problem with your approach is that you don't change the actual list contents, you just assign a different value to the name `i` (which represented a list element *until* you assigned a different value to it with `i = i*2`). If you want it to work in-place you would need to modify the list itself: e.g. `pnr[idx] *= 2` or `pnr[idx] = pnr[idx] * 2`.

However, it's generally easier to just create a new list instead of modifying an existing one.

For example:

```
def produkt(pnr):
    newpnr = []                       # create a new list
    for idx, value in enumerate(pnr, 1):
        # If you're testing for not-zero you can omit the "!=0" because every
        # non-zero number is "truthy".
        if idx % 2:  
            newpnr.append(value * 2)  # append to the new list
        else:
            newpnr.append(value)      # append to the new list
    return newpnr                     # return the new list

>>> produkt([1,2,3])
[2, 2, 6]
```

Or even better: use a generator function instead of using all these `append`s:

```
def produkt(pnr):
    for idx, value in enumerate(pnr, 1):
        if idx % 2:
            yield value * 2
        else:
            yield value

>>> list(produkt([1,2,3]))   # generators should be consumed, for example by "list"
[2, 2, 6]
```

Of course you could also just use a list comprehension:

```
def produkt(pnr):
    return [value * 2 if idx % 2 else value for idx, value in enumerate(pnr, 1)]

>>> produkt([1,2,3])
[2, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work, as `i` is no reference to the value inside the list, but just its value.

You have to store the new value in the list again.

```
def produkt(pnr):
    for i in range(len(pnr)):
        if pnr[i] % != 0:
            pnr[i] *= 2
    return pnr
```

or use this more convenient solution:

```
def produkt(pnr):
    return [x * 2 if x % 2==0 else x for x in pnr]
```

Edit: As the question has been changed (completely) you should use this code:

```
def produkt(pnr):
    return [x * 2 if ind % 2 else x for ind, x in enumerate(pnr)]
```

The first examples multiply each odd index by `2` and the former code multiplies the numbers at odd indices by `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def produkt(pnr):
    return [ 2*x if i % 2 == 0 else x for i, x in enumerate(pnr)]
```

It will double every element in your list with an odd index.

```
>>> produkt([1,2,3])
[2, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget all the previous answer and use numpy (1Ox faster).

```
np_pnr = np.array(pnr)
def produkt3():
    np_pnr[::2] *= 2
    return np_pnr
```

If for some reason you can't use numpy, you can divide the time of the previous answer by 2:

```
def produkt(pnr):
    for i in range(0,len(pnr),2):
        pnr[i] *= 2
    return pnr
```

speed test:

```
from timeit import Timer
import numpy as np


pnr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
np_pnr = np.array(pnr)

def produkt1():
    for i in range(0,len(pnr),2):
        pnr[i] *= 2
    return pnr
    
def produkt2():
    return [p*2 if i%2 else p for i,p in enumerate(pnr,1)]

def produkt3():
    np_pnr[::2] *= 2
    return np_pnr


pnr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(produkt1())
pnr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(produkt2())

print(produkt3())

expSize = 100000

t1 = Timer("produkt1()", "from __main__ import produkt1")
st1 = t1.timeit(number=expSize)
print("st1: ",st1)

t2 = Timer("produkt2()", "from __main__ import produkt2")
st2 = t2.timeit(number=expSize)
print("st2: ",st2)

t3 = Timer("produkt3()", "from __main__ import produkt3")
st3 = t3.timeit(number=expSize)
print("st3: ",st3)
```

RESULT :

```
[2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6, 14, 8, 18, 10]
[2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6, 14, 8, 18, 10]
[ 2  2  6  4 10  6 14  8 18 10]
st1:  0.763418159000139
st2:  1.6379467550013942
st3:  0.15434717799871578
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that i is a copy of the values in the pnr list, not the value in the list itself. So, you are not changing the list when doing i = i * 2.

The existing answers are already good and show the idiomatic way to achieve your goal. However, here is the minimum change to make it work as expected for learning purpose.

```
  produkt(pnr):
     new_pnr = list(pnr)
     for ix in len(new_pnr):
         if new_pnr[ix] % 2 != 0:
            new_pnr[ix] *= 2
  return new_pnr
```

Without new_pnr you'd be changing the list in place and then you wouldn't need to return it.